# How to use multiple url parameters to show/hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, url-parameters

Hoping to find a way to have multiple URL parameters display specific divs for certain products, while hiding all the other product divs.

For example:

[website.com/?product=widget1,widget3,widget4](http://website.com/?product=widget1,widget3,widget5)

or

[website.com/?product=widget1&product=widget3&product=widget4](http://website.com/?product=widget1&product=widget3&product=widget4)

The above would display the 3 divs associated with each of those 3 parameters and hide all others. See below.

`<div class="widget1 product-selector">Widget1</div>` SHOW

`<div class="widget2 product-selector">Widget2</div>` HIDE

`<div class="widget3 product-selector">Widget3</div>` SHOW

`<div class="widget4 product-selector">Widget4</div>` SHOW

`<div class="widget5 product-selector">Widget5</div>` HIDE

The example on the following site achieves similar, but it will only allow for a single URL parameter:
http://jennamolby.com/how-to-display-dynamic-content-on-a-page-using-url-parameters/

Appreciate any solutions to help me achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Php: `if(!empty($_GET['widget1']){ code for widget 1 }`

Comment: Hi admcfajn - Can you expand a bit more on this and what addition is needed to pull url parameters for this, especially multiple parameters? Thanks

Comment: every url parameter is added to $_GET[] in php. try typing `echo $_GET['something]` on a page where you have `?something=someValue `in the url. There is also the `$_POST[]` which contains variables sent to the page via a post request, and the `$_REQUEST` array contains either or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameter should have unique variable name. Keep only one parameter 'product' and values should be separated by some special character like pipe/comma. Try following solutions, it use one parameter.

http://localhost:8080/test.html?product=widget2,widget3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .product-selector{
  display: none;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="widget1 product-selector">Widget1</div>

<div class="widget2 product-selector">Widget2</div>

<div class="widget3 product-selector">Widget3</div>

<div class="widget4 product-selector">Widget4</div>

<div class="widget5 product-selector">Widget5</div>
<script>
(function() {
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
  var products = getParameterByName('product');
  products = products.split(',');
  products.forEach((product) => {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName(product)[0];
    el.style.display = 'block';
  });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this solve your problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. Works perfectly. Thank you omui for your quick solution!